# Writing Command Line information to remote machine or web service?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

I hope one of you could help me with a quick query that I have, as follows. I have a corridor rooms (about a 100 machines) and I want to collect the hostname of each. I have access to the command line and I want to capture The IP Configuration of each machine, previous to this (when I had fewer machines to document) I would issue command ipconfig -all, I would then copy this into an email
with the room number and send this to myself. I do this because I have no write access to any of the local drives and therefore use my browser to send myself the information.
Is there any way that I could send this information via the command line to a remote machine, let’s say a webserver? I’m open to suggestions as to what sort of service I'd need running on the remote machine to facilitate this, over to you geniuses? Many thanks in advance for your input.
Ralph

Comment: Why not just run an IP scanner from one pc to collect all ip addresses? www.advanced-ip-scanner.com provides one of the best ip scanners for windows. It can run portable, so you could put it on an USB stick.

Comment: I'm not real clear on the question (perhaps I'm influenced from reading part of the first answer).  Are you just trying to run any command of your choosing on a remote system, or is there some specific info that you are seeking to gather?  Why can you run IPConfig but not other commands?  [PSExec/more](https://www.gracefulsecurity.com/when-anti-virus-eats-metasploits-psexec-running-windows-commands-remotely/) shows how to use WMIC, which is bundled into newer Windows versions.  Otherwise, maybe [XCmd.exe](http://linkwithweb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Utilities/RemoteExecution/xCmd/bin/xCmd.exe)?

Answer (score 0):

### At one PC, gathering data remotely

The command [`net view`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490719.aspx) provides a list of names of currently active Windows PCs in the same workgroup or domain. It will include Samba servers (i.e. PCs and other appliances running Linux with the Samba service enabled)

### Visiting each PC and appending data to a network share

If you create a public share first (details depend on what login account you use an each of your 100 pcs)

```
 ipconfig /all >> \\SERVERNAME\Sharename\ipconfigs.txt
```